# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^{4}}{1+6^{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Problem:

> Compute
>   $$I=\displaystyle\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^{4}}{1+6^{x}}dx$$

Wolfram Alpha gave me :

$$I=\frac{32}{5}$$

I used $y=-x$ and then integral became:

$$I=\displaystyle\int\limits_{-2}^{2}\frac{6^{x}x^{4}}{1+6^{x}}dx$$
 But I don't know how to complete, I don't have no ideas.

I am waiting for your solution.

---

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3x/439856#439856

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540125/how-to-find-this-integral-i-int-pi-pi-fracx-sinx-arctanex1-co/540128#540128

Answer (score 10):

Notice that $$I+I=\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{x^{4}}{1+6^{x}}dx+\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{6^{x}x^{4}}{1+6^{x}}dx=\int_{-2}^2x^4dx.$$

Answer (score 6):

You are going in the right direction. Add the $2$ different expressions of $I$ and you get
$$2I=\int_{-2}^2 \frac{(1+6^x)x^4}{1+6^x} dx=\int_{-2}^2 x^4 dx$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Typo in denominator? Should be $1 + 6^x$

Comment: @Nicholas Roberts Yes. Apologies, I'll fix it.